# how to use k-means clustering for more features

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

I am new to machine learning, now I am learning k-means clustering. I have a lot of doubts about that. my CSV file is have Mall_Customers

```
    CustomerID  Genre   Age Annual Income (k$)  Spending Score (1-100)
0   1            Male   19      15                39
1   2            Male   21      15                81
2   3            Female 20      16                6
3   4            Female 23      16                77
4   5            Female 31      17                40
```

I want to perform k-means for the above csv file for predict the who are spednding more money in mall. here the features are AnnualIncome and Spendin Score. so my model give the output in two dimentional. If suppose i need to perform with more than 2 feature variable, on that time my model goes to more than 2-dimention or not?

1 > How to perform k-means clustering for more than 2 features ?
2 > If suppose i have 5 feature field in my csv file, how to reduce the number of features?

Comment: There is *nothing* preventing k-means to work with more than just 2 features (and in reality, it is seldom used with only 2 features).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer your question in two parts

1. If you have more than 2 features, the k means clustering happens in n dimensional space where n is number of features.The number of dimensions in the vector of each sample would change and there is no need to change algorithm or approach.
2. If you want to bring down the number of features for visualisation, you can do it using PCA (Principal Component Analysis). This is an unsupervised dimensionality reduction technique.You can read more on it.

For doing both of these, you can use python sklearn library.